# Can I buy the normal leap motion pack and download the SDK

Tags: sdk, leap-motion

I'm wondering what the difference is between the leap motion consumer and developer version? I can see there is a mount for Oculus (which I dont need). However, is there anything else included in the developer version I do need. I understand I can get the SDK from the website anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is only one Leap Motion Controller -- the mount is an accessory for it. If you just want to do desktop development, the controller is all you need :D